# How do i stop anyone from entering these special characters characters?

Tags: html, html-input

Basically I don't want a user to input the following: (!@#$%^&*()_+[]{}';:".<>?)
given that this is my code:

```
<div class = "form-item">
                    <label for = "Name">Name: </label>
                    <input type = "text" id = "Name" name="Cname">
                </div>
```

how do i do this? hopefully you can do it using the code given

We tried the regex on JavaScript but to be honest i don't understand it.

Comment: can you use javascript?

Comment: You should prevent it also on you backend

Comment: Using the HTML `pattern` attribute: `<input pattern="[^ \(!@#$%^&*\(\)_\+\[\]{}';:&quot;.&lt;&gt;\?\)]+" type = "text" id = "Name" name="Cname">`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you don't really need regex.  Just create a string of your special characters and loop through them each time the input is changed

```js
var sc = "(!@#$%^&*()_+[]{}';:\".<>?)"


function test() {

  let input = document.getElementById('Name').value
  let last = input.substring(input.length - 1, input.length)
  
  for (i = 0; i < sc.length; i++) {
    if (last == sc.substring(i, i + 1)) document.getElementById('Name').value = input.substring(0, input.length - 1)
  }



}
```

```html
<div class="form-item">
  <label for="Name">Name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="Name" name="Cname" oninput="test()">
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can copy the script below to your javascript file or place the script inside the html like the code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        input {
            width: 250px;
            padding: 4px 10px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="type" />
    <script>
        // This will prevent special character and allow only a-z A-Z 0-9 and space
        document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
            // [^a-zA-Z0-9 ] means anything except a-z A-Z 0-9 and space
            var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$");
            // if keypress is not a-z A-Z 0-9 and space then prevent it
            var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
            if (regex.test(str)) {
                return true;
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```